# Render inside AND outside normals?

Tags: normals

I have a model of a process tank and I'm trying to set it so that both the outside AND inside the tank are visible. I've gone through a number of posts about normals and such but recalculating them doesn't seem to fix my particular issue? Maybe its not normals I should be looking at? Pretty new-ish to Blender so forgive me if this is obvious.

From the picture, I'm trying to render the inner tank area as well as the outside.
[image][image: Here's an image of the render, outside on the left, inside on the right]

Comment: Hello, what does render both inside and outside means? could you please show some pictures with this kind of render?

Comment: Hello!, sorry for the confusion. Added another picture. The outside of the tank (left) seems to be fine but the inside of it (right) is just, invisible? Normals don't seem to be the issue but I'm new so I'm guessing I'm just missing something silly.

Comment: Are you using blender internal for the render engine? Cycles and eevee both render "normal" normals and backfacing normals by default

Comment: The model is being exported into Unity. Do I need to change which render I am using when exporting? Again, apologies if this is obvious lol

Comment: it seems to me that you're just not getting enough light into the inside of the object.

Comment: In general, any face in 3d is one-sided, i.e normal can be facing only one way. Pretty much all game engines render faces only from one side, when normal is pointing somewhat towards camera. As you're exporting to a game engine, it isn't related at all which render engine you use to preview the mesh, engine will be the one. To make mesh visible from inside and outside, you need to solidify mesh (give it thickness), completely or partially, to create second layer of faces with normals pointing inside.